# create mongodb user to only read in replica set (not in master)

Tags: mongodb

We have a Mongodb with ReplicaSet and a readonly user. This user can read from both Master and Replica Set. Some of the developers might accidentally run heavy queries from Master with this readonly user. Can be restricted to readonly in ReplicaSet instance and not in Master?

Answer (score 1):

User authorizations are same automatically at primary and secondary nodes, so answer is no.